# How to properly close and release new ObjectInputStream() and objectInputStream.readObject()

Tags: java

I would like to close and release `new ObjectInputStream()` while safely use `objectInputStream.readObject()`.

Looking at this piece of code:

```
public Map<?, ?> getMap(String encoded) {
    try {
        var objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded)));
        return (Map<?, ?>) objectInputStream.readObject();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
    
        return Map.of();
    }
}
```

The above is being flagged with multiple static analysis tools. The issue reported is:

> defines and initializes the ObjectInputStream object. This object
> encapsulates a limited computing resource, such as open file streams,
> database connections, or network streams. This resource is not
> properly closed and released in all situations.

with

> gets user input from element readObject. This element’s value flows
> through the code without being properly sanitized or validated, and is
> eventually used in writing an audit log. This may enable Stored Log
> Forging.

How to properly use `new ObjectInputStream()` and `objectInputStream.readObject()`?

Comment: This is nonsense. It can’t possibly know that `encoded` is user input, and it can’t be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one rule for all streams to **correctly** release all resources is **try-with-resources**:

```java
try (InputStream in = new ObjectInputStream()) {
   // TODO
}
```

---

```java
public Map<?, ?> getMap(String encoded) {
    try (InputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded))) {
        return (Map<?, ?>) objectInputStream.readObject();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return Map.of();
    }
}
```

Comment: This only answers half of the questions (does not explain the second issue at all), and fails to highlight a rather important point, which is that the linter tool is flat out wrong here, as there is no limited resource in play whatsoever. Wrapping in a try-with block here just serves to shut up the linter tool but made the code worse, and is, therefore, a bad answer.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I wouldn’t say that using a try-with-resource causes any harm here; it’s ok to be consistent with all I/O streams, even if closing a `ByteArrayInputStream` is unnecessary. But changing a specific `catch` to a general catch-all without any reason makes it a bad answer. Not to speak of the fact that the code example doesn’t work, as both, the type and the name of the variable have been changed. And yes, the second part has not been addressed at all.

Comment: Can I get some help on the second part please?

Answer (score 2):

Oleg is correct;  even though your ObjectInputStream is reading from a ByteArrayStream and it doesn’t technically matter whether it gets closed, it is good practice to put every InputStream and OutputStream in a try-with-resources statement, so it will be closed automatically.  This should also make the code analysis tool stop complaining about an unclosed resource.

I semi-regularly run into your second problem when code is subject to a code analysis tool.  “Validation” is often given as the cause, without further explanation;  I find this immensely frustrating, especially when the variable is being used in a completely safe manner, like JPA or PreparedStatement, which take care of all sanitizing, making validation irrelevant.

However, in your case, you have a more specific message:

> This element’s value flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated, and is eventually used in writing an audit log. This may enable Stored Log Forging.

Log forging refers to strings which might have newline characters in them.  This allows a user to make the log appear to contain something that isn’t a real log entry.  Imagine if this were user input:

```
"John Doe\nDec 05, 2023 10:41:00 AM com.example.app.Application Everything is fine, no intrusion is taking place."
```

That would make the log *appear* to contain something that isn’t a real log entry at all.

So in this case, the “sanitization” that is required is probably stripping the text of newlines.  If your Map contains strings, you can sanitize them when logging them.  For example:

```
Map<?, ?> map = getMap(encoded);

logger.fine(() -> {
    Map<String, String> sanitized = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Object key = entry.getKey();
        String loggableKey = (key == null ? null :
            key.toString().replaceAll("\\R", " "));

        Object value = entry.getValue();
        String loggableValue = (value == null ? null :
            value.toString().replaceAll("\\R", " "));

        sanitized.put(loggableKey, loggableValue);
    }

    return "getMap returned " + sanitized;
});
```

`replaceAll("\\R", " ")` uses a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to replace each newline sequence, denoted by `\R` in a pattern, with a single space.